# Selenium - Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I'm trying to use Selenium 3.5.2 with C #, but I always get the error "Unable to find a matching set of capabilities" every time I try to instantiate the webdriver.

I'm currently using Visual studio 2015 with Selenium 3.5.2, GeckoDriver 0.18 64bit and Firefox 55.0.3 64bit.

Here the code:

```
var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(DriverPath, DriverName);
driverService.FirefoxBinaryPath = FirefoxPath;

var firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
var webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService, firefoxOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);

webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

Where DriverPath, DriverName and FirefoxPath are respectively path of geckodriver executable, geckodriver executable name and firefox executable path (they seems to be fine, when I run the code I can see the firefox slashscreen and geckodriver prompt console).

Does anyone know how to avoid this error?

Comment: Why not installing the driver via nugget? `Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver -Version 3.5.2`

Comment: I just tried your code with the same version of the WebDriver and I didn't get an error message.  VS 2015, C#, WebDriver 3.5.2.0, geckodriver.exe dated 6/9/20117

Comment: You probably have installed something incorrectly or missed something. I would suggest that you install your drivers and any other library using NuGet. It makes all this super easy. You can find it in VS under Project > Manage NuGet Packages... Just search for the drivers and libraries you want to install and it does it all for you. I've never had an issue after that. It will also tell you when there are updates and you can use the same panel to install them. It can't get much easier...